# QSettings with multiple values for each key

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to have multiple values for each key, stored in a **human-readable** (no binaries) .ini file, using `QSettings`?

Something that could look like:

```
key_1=value_1,value2
key_2=value_1
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use QStringList type:

```
QStringList list;
list << "value_1" << "value2";
settings.setValue("key_1", list);
```

Output:

> > key_1=value_1, value2

Items that contains `,` will be quoted using `"..."`.

Answer (score 0):

Well from depends how you want to access it, you could use

```
QVariant    value ( const QString & key, const QVariant & defaultValue = QVariant() ) const
```

in which you would be able to insert a QVariantList.

But i see there is a group format.
http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qsettings.html#childGroups